# I think my post was wrongly deleted

Tags: discussion

I answered this question: [AVCaptureSession with multiple previews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543075/avcapturesession-with-multiple-previews). Then on the related question I called out it was a duplicate question and linked to the original answer. My answer was deleted and I am unsure why. I was trying to link everyone back to the original answer instead of just reposting everything. Also, I don't think I did anything against what is listed on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Related Questions:

[Double AVCaptureSession output on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448453/double-avcapturesession-output-on-ios?lq=1)

[How to display 2 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on screen simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411827/how-to-display-2-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-on-screen-simultaneously?lq=1)

[iOS Display same camera feed on two different views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924165/ios-display-same-camera-feed-on-two-different-views?lq=1)

[Double camera output in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724193/double-camera-output-in-ios?lq=1)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167643/870028

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @andrew-barber I've never done this before. Did I do it right?

Comment: Comments directed at an individual do not notify that individual unless they are already a participant on the post.

Comment: Yes, you did do this right; as far as asking into the matter. You have *also* done it right in that you came here seeking an answer, not just to rant. +1 from me for that. And of course, keep @RobertHarvey's comment above in mind :)

Comment: Errr... my comment above regarding not ranting was *not* meant to suggest Johhny has ranted elsewhere! Just that this type of question sometimes comes as a rant from others.

Comment: Thanks go to you for helping me do it the right way. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448453/double-avcapturesession-output-on-ios?lq=1) was definitively answered some time ago, and your answer merely repeats information that is already present in the accepted answer.

Answers aren't the right place to point out duplicate questions.  Use comments to do this, or vote to close if you have close privileges.  If you feel strongly about it, cast a moderator flag and cite the duplicate question.

Comment: That makes sense. So then because it is a duplicate question, would it go unanswered because it is linked to a question with an answer?

Comment: If it gets closed as a dupe, that will prevent further answers from being posted to it, yes.

Comment: Another question: Because I am linking to a new way to accomplish what the question is asking, should I do a summary of what is contained in my original answer instead of linking?

Comment: If they're the same questions, we should just close it as a dupe.  They can find the correct answer on the original question.

Comment: What about the case of the question already having an accept answer, could I go into more detail about how that answer isn't the best way?

Comment: If you feel so inclined.  If you're merely engaging in dialogue, comments are a better place for that.